# update DataFrame in Dash after text input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I want to update my DataFrame that feeds my graphs in *realtime*. In all the tutorials I have found, the DataFrame is created before creating the app layout. I want to take the input from the input component with the `username_input` ID and use that in the `get_dataFrame` function to create my initial DataFrame which will create the figure which will be used in the graph component.

```
app = Dash(__name__)

df = get_dataFrame(username_input)

fig = px.line(df, x='end', y="user",color="class")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Input(
            id="username_input",
            placeholder="username",
            type='text'
        ),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    ),
])
```

I don't fully understand how to structure the code so that this is possible. In essence I want a user input first and then after the user input all the dash data updates to reflect the new input. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move your dataframe and figure creation into your callback, then return a new figure after the user's input comes in. Working example:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, no_update
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np


app = Dash(__name__)


def get_dataFrame(username_input):
    data = np.random.rand(10) * len(username_input)
    return pd.DataFrame({"end": [*range(10)], "user": data, "class": ["red"] * 10})


fig = px.line()

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Input(id="username_input", placeholder="username", type="text"),
        dcc.Graph(id="example-graph", figure=fig),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("example-graph", "figure"), Input("username_input", "value"),
)
def func(username_input: str):

    if username_input:
        df = get_dataFrame(username_input)
        fig = px.line(df, x="end", y="user", color="class")
        return fig
    return no_update


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```